# How do I save my Redmi Note 8/4GB from app discards?

Tags: ram, multitasking, swap

I am a power user and I mostly switch a lot between apps, so I don't like discarding.

I use a **custom ROM** which is less heavy than **MIUI ROM** yet Still my background apps take a lot of memory that multitasking without discarding is not possible even with 4GB + 2GB zRAM I have.

Do you know any workaround for this without buying a new phone nor sacrificing apps, knowing that when I run `cpuinfo` in terminal: It doesn't show `swp` in features, so I don't think the **swap** will work out of the box with me and using a swap partition in my SD card will make the phone slow also except if there is a way to partition the internal storage or `/data`.